# MySQL Grant using MySQL .Net connector

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database on a remote server called qrtest_db and thru putty I have connected in and given all privileges to it. In my C# application I can access it just fine for normal day to day stuff, updating, inserting deleting etc. 
And when I do SHOW GRANTS I get back the following...

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'myIpAddress' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'myPasswordencrypted' 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `qrtest_db`.* TO 'root'@'myIpAddress'
```

But if I try to run a GRANT statement in C# like as follows . . .

```
"GRANT USAGE ON qrtest_db.* to 'root'@'" + someIPAddress + "' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPassword'";
```

then on the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery I get the message back. . .

Access denied for user 'root'@'myIPAddress' to database 'qrtest_db'

Does anybody have any ideas as to why this is this happening?
Is grant not allowed remotely thru the .Net connector?
I can sit at the console and grant rights all day long.

Comment: Can you just run a general select query with the exact same code (without the grant obviously).  It may be as simple as not having permission to log into the mysql server via your development machine (which is what the error message indicates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You dont have `GRANT` privilege.**
Becasue `ALL PRIVILEGES` does not contain `GRANT` privilege. <sup>[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_all)</sup>

You created a `'root'@'myIpAddress'` user with `all privileges`. It does not contain GRANT. Then you used this newly created user (`'root'@'myIpAddress'`) to connect to db server. Your C# application is using `'root'@'myIpAddress'` user to connect to the db server. When you enter `GRANT` command through C#, it fails. Because this user(`'root'@'myIpAddress'`) dont have GRANT option. You didn't created it that way.

You should have created user with these statements (`WITH GRANT OPTION` appended)

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'myIpAddress' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'myPasswordencrypted' with GRANT OPTION
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `qrtest_db`.* TO 'root'@'myIpAddress' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: He says he can issue this grant statement from a "console" without a problem, so I doubt this is the problem.

Comment: @Coding, He created a `'root'@'myIpAddress'` user with all privilege. all does not contain GRANT. Then he used this newly created user `'root'@'myIpAddress'` to connect to db server. His C# application is using `'root'@'myIpAddress'` user to connect to the db server. When he enters Grant command through C#. It fails because this user dont have `GRANT` option.

Comment: You are right, I misread his statement, my initial reading it sounded like those first two GRANT's that he listed were what he was trying to grant.  But on second reading, I see he says that's what the output of `SHOW GRANTS` is.

Comment: that was the problem! I figured it out 2 days ago when I was WITH GRANT OPTION in some other code online. When I saw it, I KNEW that was where the issue was! Thanks for the response to all! Shiplu you rock! I paid to be on Experts Exchange and never got a correct response because they just seemed to refuse to read what the actual question was and kept trying to steer me to localhost does not have all privileges related issues. Thanks again Shiplu and coding Gorilla.